# Angular universal: File to import not found or unreadable: ~src/main.scss

Tags: angular

I created a fresh project with `ng new` and ran following commands ([ref](https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-deep-dive-dc442a6be7b7)):

1. `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject my-project-name`
2. `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

This enabled server side rendering on port 4000.

Everything fine till this point.

Now I added a `main.scss`. and then in `my app.component.scss`, I imported with the `tilde` syntex as follows:

```
@import "~src/main.scss";
```

Now on running `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` I get following error:

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@import "~src/main.scss";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ~src/main.scss.
      in D:\nodebook2\angular-universal-test\src\app\app.component.scss (line 1, column 1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-universal-test@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles: `ng build --prod && ng run angular-universal-test:server:production`
```

---

Any workaround except for replacing `~src` with "regular" paths? (I have project with 100s of components, all using `~src` to import scss files)

Comment: Have same problem here, any solution?

Comment: nope. I had to replace all paths containing ~src to relative paths, manually